# Loopback, declared 2 remote methods in the same model but can only use one in the api explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to make 2 remote methods work in the same loopback model but only one is working in the api explorer. If I comment/delete the code of one of them the other one works perfectly. Here is how I'm trying to achive it:

```
module.exports = function(Usrs) {

    var db = server.dataSources.wifiMongo;

    db.connect(function(err, db) {
        Usrs.authMethod = function(cb) {
            db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
                if (err)
                    return console.log('Error al encontrar la collección, err = ', err);

                collection.aggregate([{
                    "$group": {
                        _id: "$strategy",
                        count: {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $project: {
                        tmp: {
                            label: '$_id',
                            value: '$count'
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $group: {
                        _id: 'methods',
                        data: {
                            $addToSet: '$tmp'
                        }
                    }
                }], function(err, methods) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('err = ' + err);
                    } else {
                        methods[0].data.forEach(function(method) {
                            method.color = randomColor({
                                luminosity: 'bright'
                            });
                        });
                        cb(null, methods[0].data);

                    }
                });
            });
        };
    });

    Usrs.remoteMethod('authMethod', {
        http: {
            path: '/analytics/authMethod',
            verb: 'get'
        },
        returns: {
            arg: 'authMethod',
            type: 'Object'
        }
    });

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    db.connect(function(err, db) {
        if (err) return console.log('error al conectar wifiMongo, err = ', err);

        Usrs.devices = function(cb) {
            db.collection('clients', function(err, collection) {
                if (err)
                    return console.log('Error al encontrar la collección, err = ', err);
                collection.aggregate([{
                    "$group": {
                        _id: "$os",
                        count: {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }
                }], function(err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        var output = client.reduce(function(a, b) {
                            var match = b._id ? b._id.match(/(Mac|Windows|Android|iOS)/) : null;
                            match = match ? match[0] : 'Others';
                            a[match] = (a[match] || 0) + b.count;
                            return a;
                        }, {});

                        output = Object.keys(output).map(function(k) {
                            return {
                                label: k,
                                value: output[k],
                                color: randomColor({
                                    luminosity: 'bright'
                                })
                            };
                        });

                        cb(null, output);

                    }
                });
            });

        };

    });
    Usrs.remoteMethod('devices', {
        http: {
            path: '/analytics/devices',
            verb: 'get'
        },
        returns: {
            arg: 'devices',
            type: 'Object'
        }
    });


};
```

If try it in the api explorer the first one runs without error.
[image]
The other one gives me internal server error.
[image]
An logs the following:

```
Unhandled error for request GET /usrs/analytics/devices: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at Function.Usrs.devices (/home/ubuntu/loopback/common/models/usrs.js:72:6)
    at SharedMethod.invoke (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/shared-method.js:262:25)
    at HttpContext.invoke (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/http-context.js:295:12)
    at phaseInvoke (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:647:9)
    at runHandler (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:135:5)
    at iterate (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
    at Object.async.eachSeries (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:162:9)
    at runHandlers (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:144:13)
    at iterate (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:154:25
    at execStack (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:492:7)
    at RemoteObjects.execHooks (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:496:10)
    at phaseBeforeInvoke (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/remote-objects.js:643:10)
    at runHandler (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/lib/phase.js:135:5)
    at iterate (/home/ubuntu/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/node_modules/loopback-phase/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
```

I've even tried placing them in different models, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Always handle errors.

You might be getting error while connecting to wifiMongo, Once check that.

```
db.connect(function(err, db) {
    if (err){ console.log('error al conectar wifiMongo, err = ', err);
        return cb(err);
    }

    Usrs.devices = function(cb) {
```